# Return the element onmouseover

Tags: javascript, dom, return, element

I'd like to modify an element on hovering, this can't be done with css because I want to use a timer to increase the inset shadow of the hovered element.

So I tried this function in javascript:

```
var element;

function hover(hoveredElement)
{
   element = hoveredElement;
   setInterval(changeBack, 100);
}

function changeBack()
{
  element.style.boxShadow = .... ;
}
```

html:

```
<li class="span1" id="s1_1" onmouseover="hover(this.id);">...</li>
```

But I get an error saying the element is not defined. Any other way to pass the id, only using JavaScript?

Comment: There's no id attribute on that `<li` element, hence you got undefined.

Comment: I also forgot to add that here, so thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inline `onmouseover` is passing the element's id when it should be passing a reference to the element itself. Try this:

```
onmouseover="hover(this);"
```

Also, optionally, you can eliminate the global `element` variable:

```
function hover(hoveredElement) {
   setInterval(function() {
      hoveredElement.style.boxShadow = .... ;
   }, 100);
}
```

Or if you want to keep the other function separate:

```
function hover(hoveredElement){
   setInterval(function(){ changeBack(hoveredElement); }, 100);
}

function changeBack(element){
   element.style.boxShadow = .... ;
}
```

Either way means you can apply the `onmouseover="hover(this);"` to multiple elements without them sharing the same global `element` variable.